# Rails - Do we have to store uploaded file on the same web server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Do we have to store uploaded files on web server which is hosting rails app? Our rails app is hosting on a `ubuntu` server. However we would like to store uploaded files on a `file server` running `Windows`. The ubuntu server and Windows server are on the same internal network. Is it possible to do so? Or what is required to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember did something like this. I used Samba in Ubuntu for shared a folder.
I was searching some tutorials

1. http://rubyguide.blogspot.com.ar/2012/02/install-samba-server-in-ubuntu-1104.html
2. http://www.sitepoint.com/ubuntu-12-04-lts-precise-pangolin-file-sharing-with-samba/